# Prove that $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a cubic field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Suppose $\alpha \in K= \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ satisfies $\alpha^3-9\alpha-6$. The discriminant of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is $-1944=2^3\cdot 3^5$ which is not a square-free and in particular Stickelberg's identity doesn't work. From
$$\text{dist}(\mathbb{Z}[
\alpha])=\text{dist}(O_K)[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb
Z[\alpha]]^2$$ 
I know that $[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb
Z[\alpha]] \mid 18$. I found several posts answering similar questions using more advanced arguments (e.g. considering prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ and ramification index at $\mathfrak{p}$) but honestly I'm not familiar with that methods. Can anyone provide some extra guides for me? Thank you.

Comment: If you're not familiar with prime ideals and don't wish to use such (rather basic?) arguments, it would be useful to clarify how you define $O_K$ and what you *do* know about it.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K$ is just the ring of integers of $K$ (elements that are algebraic integers).  I know that if $\left\{ \alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n \right\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $K$ and $p$ is a prime such that $p^2\mid \text{dist}(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n)$, then there is a special form of integral integer $1/p(\lambda \alpha_1 +\cdots + \lambda_n a_n)$ and we can find an integral basis for $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an elementary approach.

Start by writing down a general element of $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$, which looks like $x=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2$ with $a,b,c\in \Bbb Q$.

If $y,z$ are the two conjugates of $x$, then $x$ is integral iff $x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz$ are all integers. You may then compute these three expressions as:

- $x+y+z=3a$;
- $xy+yz+zx=3a^2-9b^2+36ac-18bc+81c^2$;
- $xyz=a^3-9ab^2+6b^3+18a^2c-18abc+81ac^2-54bc^2+36c^3$.

Thus it suffices to show that $a,b,c$ must be integers when the three quantities above are integers.

If you use your knowledge that $18\mathcal O_K\subseteq \Bbb Z[\alpha]$, then we already know that $18a,18b,18c$ are integers, and it becomes a case-by-case verification that the remainders of $18a,18b,18c$ modulo $18$ can only be zeros.

It can be done more efficiently (by considering mod $2$, mod $3$, then mod $9$), but after all it's an elementary yet really complicated exercise, and in the end the main argument should be equivalent to the "more advanced arguments" you mentioned in your post.

Thus I suggest that you learn these more advanced things, which will be useful for other tasks as well.

Comment: I think this method wouldn't work in this case in practice.  If we set $a= k + e/18, b=m+f/18, c=n+g/18$, where $k,m, n$ are arbitrary integers and $0 \leq e, f , g < 18$ are also integers, then we can check when $x+y+z$ and $xy+yz+zx$ are integers and it only depends on $e, f, g$. But whether $xyz$ is an integer also depends on values of $k, m, n$, so we have infinitely many cases to check unless there is a way to rule out some cases. I doubt that it would happen.

Comment: We don't have infinitely many cases to check. We have at most $18^3$ cases to check, as $\Bbb Z[\alpha] \subseteq \mathcal O_K\subseteq \frac1{18}\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ means we only have to check which coset of $\frac1{18}\Bbb Z[\alpha]/\Bbb Z[\alpha]$ lies in $\mathcal O_K/\Bbb Z[\alpha]$. Hence a brute force way is to pick one element from each coset, calculate its minimal polynomial and see if the coefficients are integers.